# What Ampacity is allowed on a 2/3 Romex 25 ft run to subpanel?

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I have a 25' run from my main panel to my subpanel. I have #2 Copper THHN wire in the romex. It's being run through a wall in a house in Tempe Arizona. The wall has 2 sets of studs (inner and outer wall), both will be insulated, and it's running in-between.

Looking at the code, The #2 THHN 90C line in the NEC shows 130A. Then there's some calculations to derate based on ambient temperature, and there's usually length deratings (which I think don't matter because it's only 25').

In this case, do I get the 130A? Is the ambient temperature only if you're running outside? I would expect it to be something around 90F in that wall at most times, and then we would run higher amperage we would be using the AC in the house.

Thanks.

Fred

Comment: Are the wires in your NM cable *actually* marked "THHN" or are you assuming that? Normally they're not marked. When you have an NM cable, you must use the NM cable column of the ampacity chart.

Comment: Romex is a brand name that's synonymous with NM-B.  Do you have NM-B or SER cable?  Someone else can chime in, but I believe SER is rated 75 degrees C even if in wall insulation.

Comment: A) Pictures of the actual wire will help clear up ambiguity about what you've got (include the labeling if at all possible). B) 90°F is _much_ colder than 90°C. 90°F is actually colder than 60°C (the lowest temp in the tables). 60°C is 140°F...

Answer (score 3):

Wire uses the thermal rating that is the lowest of:

- the wire insulation rating
- The thermal rating of the enclosures it routes through
- the thermal rating of the terminals.

Per NEC 334.80, NM / Romex is limited to 60C thermal.  While the insulation may be made of nylon, it is certainly not proper THHN wire. The difference is obvious if you've handled either one.  In fact, NM has a vulnerability when it gets wet - the insulation leaks and it ground-faults! THHN doesn't do that.

#2 copper is 95A wire at 60C.

Assuming you did not pay 4 digits for industrial grade panels, your consumer/commercial panel enclosures and their terminals are rated 75C thermal so that's all you're going to get.

I could not guess how hot your wall gets, because I do not know how much solar gain it endures or what color it is.  334.80 permits you to use the 90C figure when computing thermal derate, which means other thermal derates are basically not a problem for NM.  Its 60C limit tends to eclipse any likely thermal derate.